# Equating two different forms of charge to mass ratio

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Looking over various textbooks on electromagnetism, I have come across two different formula for the charge to mass ratio of a particle. But I am not too sure how to prove the two formulae are equal.

They are as follows:

Consider a particle of charge $q$, mass $m$ in an electromagnetic field. Given $\vec{E} \ \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ -E \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, and $\vec{B} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ -B \end{pmatrix}$ find the charge to mass ratio of a particle.

Both methods used the fact that a particle in a magnetic field travels in circular motion, leading to:

$
\begin{align}
\vec{F_{mag}} &= \vec{F_{centripical}}\\
q \left ( \vec{v} \times \vec{B} \right ) &= m \frac{\vec{v}^{2}}{r}\\
qvB &= m \frac{v^{2}}{r}\\
\Rightarrow \frac{q}{m} &= \frac{v}{Br}
\end{align}
$

Here there is two separate approaches to finding $v$ depending on the textbook. The first of which is using work done.

$
\begin{align}
W = Vq &= \frac{1}{2} m v^{2}\\
\Rightarrow v &= \sqrt{\frac{2Vq}{m}}\\\\
\frac{q}{m} = \frac{v}{Br} &= \frac{\sqrt{2Vq}}{Br\sqrt{m}}\\
\frac{q^{2}}{m^{2}} &= \frac{2Vq}{B^{2}r^{2}m}\\
\Rightarrow \frac{q}{m} &= \frac{2V}{B^2 r^2}
\end{align}
$

The second method is done equating the electric force to the magnetic force.

$
\begin{align}
F_{E} &= F_{B}\\
qE &= q(\vec{v} \times \vec{B})\\
E &= vB\\
\Rightarrow v &= \frac{E}{B}\\\\
\frac{q}{m} = \frac{v}{Br} &= \frac{E}{B^{2} r}
\end{align}
$

So I assume $\frac{2V}{B^2 r^2} = \frac{E}{B^{2} r}$, solving for $E$ gives:

$
\begin{align}
\frac{2V}{B^2 r^2} &= \frac{E}{B^{2} r}\\
E &= \frac{2V}{r} = \frac{V}{d}\\
\therefore d \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{r}{2} \tag{1}
\end{align}
$

However, I'm unsure if this last equation (1) is actually true, and if so how can it be proven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different situations here. The electric field is used in different ways in the two situations. Each formula is OK for the specific situation.
In the first case you accelerate the particle in the electric field so the velocity depends only on the electric field (or potential difference).
In the second case you select a specific velocity with cross fields. The velocity you select depends on both E and B values.
So the formulas that give the spcific charge as a fucntion of the parameters of the experiment are different. There is no reason for them to be the same. Of course, the specific charge for a given particle will be the same, no matter what experiment you do. But the experimental parameters (E, B, r, V, etc) will be different in the two experiments.
Actually you can have both situation happening in a mass spectrometer, for example. First the particles are accelerated through a potential difference (or field E1) then passed through a velocity selector (with E2 and B1 fields) and then they are injected in the main magnetic field (B2). All these fields are different and the relation between them and the velocity of the particle is different.
You should focus on understanding the phenomena themselves and the context of each formula. The same symbol in different formulas may have different meaning (different functions) in the phenomenon,  even if the symbol  represents the same type of quantity.

Comment: Would the same work not be done by the electric field no matter what though? So would the equation in method 1 not always be true.

Comment: In the case of crossed fields there is no work done by electric field. There is no displacement along the field direction.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks.